# Inserting multiple rows into empty table

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert multiple rows into table.
I've been trying to use `.DataBodyRange.Rows(0:100).insert` but the problem is that `.DataBodyRange` returns error when the table is empty (0 rows).

So is there an alternative? Assuming I don't want to add line by line in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `.DataBodyRange` is `Nothing`, `.InsertRowRange` is something.

So you can do something like

```
If .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
    .InsertRowRange.Resize(100).Insert
Else
    .DataBodyRange.Resize(100).Insert
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got a solution to my problem.
After adding a row databodyrange no longer returns an error and segment of rows can be inserted after that row.
I'll have to check if rows(1:1) returns an error though assuming there is just 1 row.

```
                If .ListRows.Count < rowi + 1 Then
                  If .ListRows.Count = 0 Then
                    .ListRows.Add
                  End If
                .DataBodyRange.Rows(.ListRows.Count + 1 & ":" & rowi).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```